# Use Pycharm as general-purpose editor : Open all non-project (locked) files in new window

Tags: pycharm

I like PyCharm (that I customized quite a bit) more than my general purpose text editor and I would like to use it as general purpose text editor (like notepad or vim).

Problem: I have project opened and `pycharm some-file.txt` opens it in my already opened project (I don't want that, that file is unrelated and I have to confirm 'unlock' in dialog box).

Is it possible to open all these non-project files in the same window (window without project association) and use it that way?

Answer (score 0):

No, in PyCharm all files are always associated with a project. It's not really intended to be used as a general-purpose text editor.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost No, it's not too good. It's too heavy, for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Create special, *dummy* project for all external files, and select *I want to edit any non-project file in the current session* in the [Non-Project Files Access Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/non-project-files-access-dialog.html) when opening the first file.

Also vote for [IDEA-125379 Allow configuring custom folders, that prevent non-project-editing locking](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125379) and show this to others.